# How to combine two integrals containing the PDFs of a variable and its linear transform?

Tags: random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, integral

**Original Post:**

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with cumulative distribution functions $F(x)$ and $G(y)$. We know that $Y = aX + b$.

I want to compute $Z(x) = F(x) - G(y)$.

What I have so far is the following:
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)dx
$$

$$G(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y}g(y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{y}\frac{1}{|a|}f\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)dy
$$

$$Z(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)dx - \int_{-\infty}^{y}\frac{1}{|a|}f(x)dy
$$

How should I go on doing the subtraction of the integrals? Is this even possible as the integrales belong to different variables (dx and dy)?

**Solution thanks to jbowman:**

Suppose $a>0$ and $y=ax+b$

$$G(y) = P(aX+b <= y)$$
$$G(y) = P(aX+b<=ax+b) = P(X<=x) = F(x)$$
And thus:
$$Z(x,y) = F(x) - G(y) = 0$$

**Corrected Post**

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with cumulative distribution functions $F(k)$ and $G(k)$. We know that $Y = aX + b$.

I want to compute $Z(k) = F(k) - G(k)$.

**Proposed solution**

Assuming $a>0$:

$$F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{k}f(x)dx
$$

$$G(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{k}g(y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{k-b}{a}}f(x)dx
$$

$$Z(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{k}f(x)dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{k-b}{a}}f(x)dx
$$

And thus

$$Z(k) = \int_{\frac{k-b}{a}}^{k}f(x)dx
$$

Comment: Does $dy =a\ dx$?

Comment: Why wouldn't the formula $Z(x) = F(x) - F((x-b)/a)$ (for $a\gt 0;$ there's a similar one for $a\lt 0$) be an acceptable "computation" of $Z$?  It even works when $X$ does not have a density function.  In short, is this question really about distributions or is it trying to clear up some issues with the concepts or practice of integration?

Comment: What is $y$ in $Z(x) = F(x)-G(y)$?  The RHS depends on both $x$ and $y$ while the LHS depends on $x$ alone.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It seems I got confused with the variables and integration bounds, I added the corrected question to my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the case $a > 0$.  In this case, $Z(x) = 0$ for all $x$ as $y$ is a deterministic monotonically increasing function of $x$.  The probability that $y \leq 1$, for example, is equal to the probability that $x \leq (1-b)/a$, i.e., $G(1) = F((1-b)/a)$, and when $y = 1$, $x$ does $ = (1-b)/a$, so the two cumulative probabilities are equal.

If this isn't clear, consider the case $a = 1, b = 0$.

You should be able to work out the case $a < 0$ from here!

Addition to take into account @yahiro's comment:  If $a = 0$, then things work differently, as $g$ is a point mass at $b$, so $G = 0$ to the left of $b$ and $1$ at $b$ and above.  This affects $Z(x)$ in an obvious way.

Comment: Is $G(1)$ defined if $a=0$ ?

Comment: @yahiro - sure, it's either $0$ or $1$, depending upon the value of $b$.  You're making a great point, though, and I'll modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, this perfectly answers my question! Unfortunately, I did not ask the question correctly because I got confused with the variables and integration bounds. I thus added the corrected question and proposed solution to my post as well!

Comment: It happens, believe me!  And thanks for your generosity!